# What is an “empty” @about attribute?

Tags: syntax, metadata, string, xml-attribute, rdfa

In “[RDFa in XHTML: Syntax and Processing](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-rdfa-syntax-20081014),” Section 5.5, Step 4, the specifications say “if the element is the head or body element then act as if there is an empty @about present, and process it according to the rule for @about, above.” However, I can’t find any mention of how an “empty” about should be processed, nor exactly what constitutes an “empty” @about.

First, would an “empty @about consist of about=””?

Second, does it merely create an explicit bNode that has no author specified identifier? (Something that has sometimes been referred to as an “anonymous bNode” within the RDFa documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

A string with no characters is defined as an [empty attribute value](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#FixedAttr). The [RDF Semantics spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#shared-blank-nodes-informative) defines the resulting node as follows:

> Blank nodes are treated as simply indicating the existence of a thing, without using, or saying anything about, the name of that thing.

Some features are based on the existence of blank nodes:

- automation relabelling, since the strings used to label blank-nodes (implicit positions) do not matter so long as they do not collide with other such labels
- shortcuts for RDF lists

For example, an ordered list of Tennis Grand Slam names:

> the Turtle shortcut:

```
:GrandSlam :order (:AustralianOpen :FrenchOpen
:Wimbledon :USOpen)
```

> square-bracket syntax:

```
:GrandSlam :order
[ rdf:first :AustralianOpen ; rdf:rest
[ rdf:first :FrenchOpen ; rdf:rest
[ rdf:first :Wimbledon ; rdf:rest
[ rdf:first :USOpen ; rdf:rest rdf:nil ]]]]
```

> the triple-form

```
GrandSlam :order _:b1 .
_:b1 rdf:first :AustralianOpen . _:b1 rdf:rest _:b2 .
_:b2 rdf:first :FrenchOpen . _:b2 rdf:rest _:b3 
_:b3 rdf:first :Wimbledon . _:b3 rdf:rest _:b4 .
_:b4 rdf:first :USOpen . _:b4 rdf:rest rdf:nil
```

**References**

- [Everything You Always Wanted to Know About Blank Nodes ∗ (pdf)](https://epub.wu.ac.at/5332/1/365-622-1-SM.pdf)
- [Problems of the RDF model: Blank Nodes](http://milicicvuk.com/blog/2011/07/14/problems-of-the-rdf-model-blank-nodes/)